# Calculate p-value without R.

Tags: statistics

I'm revising for my Advanced Statistics exam which involves a lot of analysis on Linear Models.

A question which keeps on coming up is "Using appropriate tests find the significant terms in the ANOVA table." However, I am unsure how to do this without using R? I believe I need to find p-values, but in the exam, we aren't allowed to use R.

Here is the question in full and my attempt.

```
> fm1 <- glm(sr ~ pop15 + pop75 + dpi* ddpi,data = LifeCycleSavings)
> anova(fm1)
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model: gaussian, link: identity

Response: sr

Terms added sequentially (first to last)


         Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev
NULL                        49     983.63
pop15     1  204.118        48     779.51
pop75     1   53.343        47     726.17
dpi       1   12.401        46     713.77
ddpi      1   63.054        45     650.71
dpi:ddpi  1   52.158        44     598.55
> summary(fm1)

Call:
glm(formula = sr ~ pop15 + pop75 + dpi * ddpi, data = LifeCycleSavings)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-8.0369  -2.8419   0.0726   2.7431  10.2290  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept) 23.4272560  7.6007598   3.082  0.00354 **
pop15       -0.3347718  0.1544350  -2.168  0.03563 * 
pop75       -1.1978303  1.0808228  -1.108  0.27377   
dpi         -0.0021451  0.0012917  -1.661  0.10387   
ddpi         0.0985487  0.2479159   0.398  0.69291   
dpi:ddpi     0.0007218  0.0003686   1.958  0.05658 . 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 13.60352)

    Null deviance: 983.63  on 49  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 598.55  on 44  degrees of freedom
AIC: 280.02

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2
```

(a) Express the deviance table as a standard ANOVA table.

```
                Df  SS          MS          F-Ratio P-Value
pop15           1   204.118     204.118     15.005  ?
pop75           1   53.343      53.343      3.9213  ?
dpi             1   12.401      12.401      0.9116  ?
ddpi            1   63.054      63.054      4.6352  ?
dpi:ddpi        1   52.158      52.158      3.8342  ?
Residual        44  598.55      13.603      ——————
```

(b) Using appropriate tests find the significant terms in the ANOVA
table.

Really appreciate any help!

Comment: Presumably there are formulas you are supposed to use. Are you allowed a "cheat sheet" on the exam?

Comment: We are given a set of standard statistical tables

Comment: If those tables include a table for the F-distribution, then that's what you should use for determining the p-value.

Comment: @Raskolnikov They do, however, I am unsure how/what formula you would use to determine them, for example, in our F-table at 95% with Degrees of freedom 1 and 44 we get a value of 4.26, how do I then go on to calculate my p-values?

Comment: Apologies if this seems obvious but I can't find anything on this in our lecture notes, it just says how to do it using R.

Comment: What you can do is check if the observed F value is greater than the tabulated F value. If it is so, you reject that particular null hypothesis.